# Nodejs mongoose get results from two collections in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I run into the problem where I need to get results from two collections in NodeJS using mongoose. Basically I have `users` collection and `boughtItems` collection.

`users` collection consists of `_id` and `username`

`boughtItems` collection consists of `item_id`, `username` (user who bought item)

Can someone show how to get results from `users` and `boughtItems` so when I display all `users` their bought items will show up next to their name in the same page.

I have two models: `User` and `BoughtItem`

```
User.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "boughtitems", // collection name in db
        localField: "username",
        foreignField: "username",
        as: "boughtitems"
    }
}]).exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users);
});
```

This code block return users with boughtItems but every bought item is `[Object]` how to get full information from that `object`?

So I did `JSON.stringify(users)` and now I get all the info.

I get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYFfu.png)

How to display boughtitems in render file like this:

```
{{#each users}}
   {{this.boughtitem['item_power']}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is actually fetching the `BoughtItem` data. The issue is `console.log`, which does not print nested objects. If you want to print a whole object, try the following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
```

Comment: And now how to display the results in the file. If I do `each` I can only query `users` info from their collection. But it don't display anything from `boughtItems`. I get another array of elements next to user array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Please add the code for that to your question and show what your expected result is.

Comment: So this is what I get: {USERS ARRAY OF ELEMENTS}, {BOUGHT ITEMS ARRAY OF ELEMENTS}

Comment: And when I do `{{#each users}}` I only get info from {USERS ARRAY}, how to get info from {bought items array} also  ?

Comment: I have no idea what `{{#each users}}` means or where you're using it for rendering. Please consider making the code in your question more complete to show us how you're connecting the mongoose fetch with this code.

Comment: I aded image and the code how I want to display it.